# error trying to serialize null instant using jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I'm having some issues with jackson trying to serialize null instant objects. In my db model i have some timestamps that are nullables and i want to be able to send them like that to the client.

The thing is that when i generate the response i see always these errors:

`Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain:...`

By debugging y show the field is an Instant. This is the problematic getter...

```java
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    public Instant getStartTime() {
        return startTime.toInstant();
    }
```

I have tried to use the @JsonInclude annotation for the field, the getter and the whole class but I'm still getting that message and a 500 on the client.

I'm using Spring-boot which includes jackson 2.11.0.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check variable `startTime` is not `null` first:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public Instant getStartTime() {
    return startTime != null ? startTime.toInstant() : null;
}
```

`Jackson` invokes getter and checks whether value is `null` or not. But `NullPointerException` is thrown when `getter` is invoked.

Comment: I need to sleep more :facepalm: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Acampoh, no problem. Sometimes we can't see the forest for the trees. Comments on `SO` supports unicode symbols: . 